# Undefined index and invalid foreach arg on line 47

Tags: php, html

On my cart page I am having an issue where the product items do not show on the web page, and if I click the remove item button, I am given the two errors that I have made the title of this post. What can I do to get past these errors?

my webpage looks like this, [current webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DyTM.png) whereas it should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp0xw.png, below is the code for the page.

```
<?php

session_start();
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$db = "movie1";


try {
    $handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword");
    $handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "connected";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("something failed");
}
if (isset($_POST["add"])){
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart"])){
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"product_id");
        if (!in_array($_GET["id"],$item_array_id)){
            $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
                'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
            );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            echo '<script>window.location="Cart.php"</script>';
        }else{
            echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to Cart")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="Cart.php"</script>';
        }
    }else{
        $item_array = array(
            'product_id' => $_GET["id"],
            'item_name' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'product_price' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'item_quantity' => $_POST["quantity"],
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET["action"])){
    if ($_GET["action"] == "delete"){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $value){ // line 47
            if ($value["product_id"] == $_GET["id"]){
                unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
                echo '<script>alert("Product has been Removed...!")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="Cart.php"</script>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport"
           content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Shopping Cart</title>


     <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <style>
         .product{
             border: 1px solid #eaeaec;
             margin: -1px 19px 3px -1px;
             padding: 10px;
             text-align: center;
             background-color: #efefef;
         }
         table, th, tr{
             text-align: center;
         }
         .title2{
             text-align: center;
             color: #66afe9;
             background-color: #efefef;
             padding: 2%;
         }
         h2{
             text-align: center;
             color: #66afe9;
             background-color: #efefef;
             padding: 2%;
         }
         table th{
             background-color: #efefef;
         }

     </style>

 </head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="width: 65%">
    <h2>Ticket Cart</h2>
    <?php
    $query = $handle->query('SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id ASC');

        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


    }

    ?>

    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-16 w3-center">
        <form method="post" action="cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row ["id"];?>">
            <div class="product">
                <img src="<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class="img-responsive">
                <h5 class = "text-info"> <?php $row['pname']; ?> </h5>
                <h5 class="text-danger"><?php $row['price']; ?></h5>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row['pname']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="add" style="margin-top: 5px;" class="btn btn-success"
                       value="Add to Cart">


            </div>


        </form>
    </div>



    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <h3 class="title2"> Cart Details</h3>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th width="30%">Product Name</th>
                <th width="10%">Quantity</th>
                <th width="13%">Price Details</th>
                <th width="10%">Total Price</th>
                <th width="17%">Remove Item</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
            $total = 0;
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value["item_name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo (int)$value["item_quantity"]; ?></td>
                <td>$ <?php echo (float)$value["product_price"]; ?></td>
                <td>
                    $ <?php echo number_format((int)$value["item_quantity"] * (float)$value["product_price"], 2); ?></td>
                <td><a href="Cart.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $value["product_id"]; ?>"><span
                            class="text-danger">Remove Item</span></a></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            $total = $total + ($value["item_quantity"] * (float)$value["product_price"]);
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>
                <th align="right">$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></th>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Continue to checkout" class="btn">






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They do, you just have to read and understand them first. Which is line 47?

Comment: And show us why that does not apply on your code. Show use the array that is causing the issue.

Comment: You didn't provide the full error message, so it makes it hard to provide full information on what's wrong. But the link provided should help with the undefined index error.

Comment: @Qirel I can only see one foreach() it's in the if part just above the html

Comment: Fair enough, @Andreas!

Comment: @Qirel  I have added a comment next to the code that throws the error, it is just above the HTML

Comment: You just need one `if` before your `foreach` then, which should be `if (isset($_GET["action"]) && $_GET["action"] == 'delete' && !empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {` - no need to chain `if` conditions if they don't have any other sub-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Looking at line 114, you have a space between `$row` and `["id"]` in your form action. This is likely not passing expected information to your "functions". -- Rows 116 and 117 do not contain an echo in your php code, nor do they use the shorthand echo `<?='$row['pname']?>`. These 2 will not cause an error, but will not display your intended data.